# Unable to restrict comments to a specific post id using wordpress api v2

Tags: wordpress, api

making the following request returns every single comment from the blog. It is not restricted to the post ID in the query parameters.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

```
http://anawins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/?post=2986
```

or

```
http://anawins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=2986
```

yields:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.3
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 15:47:47 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=96jsfcdeg8ksnraq5aa3o1a3o7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: oculus-unknown-switcher=1; expires=Sun, 23-Jul-2017 15:47:46 GMT
Set-Cookie: oculus-unknown-switcher=1; expires=Sun, 23-Jul-2017 15:47:46 GMT
Set-Cookie: wp_woocommerce_session_d65537f626aa4d41876f80145673898a=a4bbe5c1e08f80685e3bf383595f1ce4%7C%7C1469461666%7C%7C1469458066%7C%7C92bf547bd7e641385bb561b739e1c87a; expires=Mon, 25-Jul-2016 15:47:46 GMT; path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization
X-WP-Total: 2549
X-WP-TotalPages: 255
Link: <http://anawins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?q=%2Fwp-json%2Fwp%2Fv2%2Fcomments%2F%3Fpost%3D2986&context=view&page=2>; rel="next"
Allow: GET
```

Notice how 2500 comments are coming back, even with that post ID.

How do I change the request so that only comments for a specific post are returned?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
http://anawins.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=1
```

Result will be

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "post": 1,
        "parent": 0,
        "author": 0,
        "author_name": "Mr WordPress",
        "author_url": "https://wp-api.org/",
        "date": "2016-05-10T07:25:45",
        "date_gmt": "2016-05-10T07:25:45",
        "content": {
            "rendered": "<p>Hi, this is a comment.<br />\nTo delete a comment, just log in and view the post&#039;s comments. There you will have the option to edit or delete them.</p>\n"
        },
        "link": "https://demo.wp-api.org/2016/05/10/hello-world/#comment-1",
        "status": "approved",
        "type": "comment",
        "author_avatar_urls": {
            "24": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=24&d=mm&r=g",
            "48": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=48&d=mm&r=g",
            "96": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/?s=96&d=mm&r=g"
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/1"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/comments"
                }
            ],
            "up": [
                {
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "post_type": "post",
                    "href": "https://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

You can do more example query at [WP Demo Rest API](http://demo.wp-api.org/)

Comment: If i make a GET request to that exact URL, the problem is the same. Over 2500 comments are returned. You can try it yourself since the site is live.

Comment: @DanSafee Over 2500 comments in one post? Or all posts of your site?

Comment: it's returning all posts for the site from the beginning of time

Comment: @DanSafee this is problem from your rest api. from your embed to this issue I can tell you that. Please replace your API source. Hope this help. I have same problem with Woocommerce Rest Api when I try to create variations of product. Because my api source have error.

Comment: Deleting the plugin and reinstalling just gives me back the same version and the same error. What version are you using?

Comment: @DanSafee Please try with another version.

Comment: What version do you recommend? I have the latest stable build

Comment: @DanSafee What's your Wordpress version? I'm sorry about late reply.